# ¿Al generar el filemtime() se muestra una fecha diferente al real del fichero?

Tags: php, html

Estoy creando un proyecto en el cual necesito saber la fecha de algunos archivos, el problema es que al momento de hacer esta función muestra otra fecha diferente a la real.

```
$carpeta = "img";
if(is_dir($carpeta)){
          if($dir = opendir($carpeta)){
              while(($archivo = readdir($dir)) !== false){
                  if($archivo != '.' && $archivo != '..' && $archivo != '.htaccess'){
                      $fechaC = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',filemtime($carpeta.'/'.$archivo));
                      echo $archivo."/".$fechaC."<br>";
                  }
              }
              closedir($dir);
          }
      }
```

El caso es que la fecha que muestra esta función es un día después al fecha de modificación.

Ejemplo:
Esa es la fecha real

[image: La fecha de creación]

Y esta es la fecha que muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es posible que la zona horaria del SO y de PHP no coincidan, prueba a establecer la zona horaria con `date_default_timezone_set` https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php si esto no resuelve tu problema comentamelo. Aqui puedes obtener un listado de las zonas horarias admitidas https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.php

Comment: Muchas gracias si funciono, ya me mostró la fecha y hora correcta

Comment: Me alegro te escribo una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En estos casos suele suceder que la zona horaria del sistema operativo y de PHP no son la misma, siempre que vayamos a trabajar con fechas es recomendable establecer la zona ahoraria.

Podemos establecer la zona horaia con [`date_default_timezone_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Ejemplo:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');

$carpeta = "img";
if(is_dir($carpeta)){
    if($dir = opendir($carpeta)){
        while(($archivo = readdir($dir)) !== false){
            if($archivo != '.' && $archivo != '..' && $archivo != '.htaccess'){
                $fechaC = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',filemtime($carpeta.'/'.$archivo));
                echo $archivo."/".$fechaC."<br>";
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }
}
```

Podemos encontrar un listado de las zonas horarias admitidas en el [Listado de zonas horarias admitidas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.php) del manual.